# program in c++. size of char array is 5 but value more than 5 char is also accepted

Tags: c++

this is a short program in c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  char s[5];
  cout<<"enter your name"<<endl;
  cin>>s;
  cout<<"Hello"<<s<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

value greater than 5 are also accepted 
what is the concept behind it??

Comment: Please correctly format your post next time - check the preview before you submit.

Comment: This is why you should use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: Unfortunately, `>>` is not going to respect your buffer size. Try `cin.get()` instead to explicitly read `n` chars.

Answer (score 5):

You're indeed correct. To attempt to put any more than 5 characters (including a null-termimator) into `s` is *undefined behaviour*.

In C++, the best thing to do is to use a `std::string` instead. Appropriate overloads for `<<` and `>>` are provided for `std::string`.